# list grep results in one line?

Tags: grep, ls

A quick question: `ls . | grep -E "^[0-9]"` gives me the results in the following format:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I let it be simply displayed as `1 2 3 4 5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ls . | grep -E "^[0-9]" | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo
```

Comment: \o/ Lost the race with Kent though ;)

Answer (score 2):

try this with `tr`:

```
your cmd ....|tr "\n" ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

try `ls . | grep -E "^[0-9" | tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 1):

Using  `awk`

```
ls . | awk '/^[0-9]/ {printf "%s ",$0}'
```

Or more clean:

```
ls . | awk '/^[0-9]/ {printf "%s ",$0} END {print ""}'
```

Comment: @Daniel Added the space.

Answer (score 1):

If it is available, you can use the `column` command from `bsdmainutils`:

```
ls | grep '^[0-9]' | column
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Another test:

```
seq 50 | column
```

Example output:

```
1   6   11  16  21  26  31  36  41  46
2   7   12  17  22  27  32  37  42  47
3   8   13  18  23  28  33  38  43  48
4   9   14  19  24  29  34  39  44  49
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
```